# Collections of subsets on $\mathbb{ℝ}$ are bases

Tags: general-topology

I'm just beginning to learn topology and have some questions about basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I believe $B=\{\{x\}|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates the discrete topology, and I also believe $B=\{(x,x+1]|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates the the upper limit topology.

Is $\{(x,\infty)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$? And if so, how does that differ from $\{(x-1,x)\cup(x,\infty)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the set of singletons is a basis for the discrete topology. Similarly, $\{(a, a+1]: a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates the upper limit topology; however, it is not a [*basis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) but rather just a [*subbasis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) for this topology.

The distinction: any family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ is a subbasis of a topology on $X$ - namely, the smallest topology $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ such that every $A\in\mathcal{F}$ is open. Elements of $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ are unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{F}$. In case $\mathcal{F}$ elements of $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ are just unions of elements of $\mathcal{F}$, we say $\mathcal{F}$ is a *basis* for $\tau_\mathcal{F}$; this happens exactly when, for all $A, B\in\mathcal{F}$, we have for all $x\in A\cap B$ some $C_x\in\mathcal{F}$ with $x\in C_x\subseteq A\cap B$. (Note that if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ this is trivially satisfied.)

As to your other questions, $\{(x, \infty): x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (call it "$\mathcal{B}$") is indeed a basis for a topology, $\tau$. It's a good exercise to show that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\tau$ iff $A$ is of the form $(x, \infty)$ for some $x$ - that is, the *only* open sets are the basic open sets.

By contrast, $\{(x-1, x)\cup(x, \infty): x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (call it "$\mathcal{C}$") is not a basis (think about $x=1$ and $x=1.1$ . . .). The topology $\sigma$ with subbasis $\mathcal{C}$ is a bit complicated to describe, but it's certainly not $\tau$ - e.g. $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ is open in $\sigma$ but not in $\tau$.

Comment: If for "A" it was $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, would it then be a basis for a topology?

Comment: @Learner Yes. (Also I was going too fast and screwed up the definition of basis; it's fixed now.)